# how to fix a chatbot that brings an error when I message it some comments

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, nlp

I have a python chatbot that uses simple machine learning model i.e. decision tree classification to train the model that will be used to decide the response.

```
import random
import json
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

lemmatizeer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())
words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['text']:
        word_list = word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['intent']))
        if intent['intent'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['intent'])

words = [lemmatizeer.lemmatize(w) for w in words if w not in ignore_letters]

words = sorted(set(words))
print(words)
classes = sorted(set(classes))

training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizeer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training, dtype=object)
train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, criterion='entropy')
classifier.fit(train_x, train_y)
pred_y = classifier.predict(train_x)
print(accuracy_score(train_y, pred_y))
print('Done training')

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [lemmatizeer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words

def bag_of_words(sentence):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag) 

def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = bag_of_words(sentence)
    res = classifier.predict(np.array([bow]).reshape(1, -1))[0]
    print(res)
    ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
    results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({'intentd': classes[r[0]], 'probability': str(r[1])})
    return return_list

def get_response(intent_list, intent_json):
    tag = intent_list[0]['intentd']
    list_of_intent = intent_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intent:
        if i['intent'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result

print("GO! BOT is running")

while True:
    message = input("")
    ints = predict_class(message)
    res = get_response(ints, intents)
    print(res)
```

The dataset used for training is from intents from intents.json files.

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "intent": "Greeting",
            "text": [
                "Hi",
                "Hi there",
                "Hola",
                "Hello",
                "Hello there",
                "Hya",
                "Hya there"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Hi human, please tell me your GeniSys user",
                "Hello human, please tell me your GeniSys user",
                "Hola human, please tell me your GeniSys user"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "GreetingUserRequest",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "GreetingResponse",
            "text": [
                "My user is Adam",
                "This is Adam",
                "I am Adam",
                "It is Adam",
                "My user is Bella",
                "This is Bella",
                "I am Bella",
                "It is Bella"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Great! Hi <HUMAN>! How can I help?",
                "Good! Hi <HUMAN>, how can I help you?",
                "Cool! Hello <HUMAN>, what can I do for you?",
                "OK! Hola <HUMAN>, how can I help you?",
                "OK! hi <HUMAN>, what can I do for you?"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "extensions.gHumans.updateHuman",
                "entities": true,
                "responses": [
                    "Hi %%HUMAN%%! How can I help?",
                    "Hi %%HUMAN%%, how can I help you?",
                    "Hello %%HUMAN%%, what can I do for you?",
                    "Hola %%HUMAN%%, how can I help you?",
                    "OK hi %%HUMAN%%, what can I do for you?"
                ]
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "GreetingUserRequest",
                "out": "",
                "clear": true
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": [
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 3,
                    "rangeTo": 4
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 2,
                    "rangeTo": 3
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 1,
                    "rangeTo": 2
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 2,
                    "rangeTo": 3
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 3,
                    "rangeTo": 4
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 2,
                    "rangeTo": 3
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 1,
                    "rangeTo": 2
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 2,
                    "rangeTo": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "intent": "CourtesyGreeting",
            "text": [
                "How are you?",
                "Hi how are you?",
                "Hello how are you?",
                "Hola how are you?",
                "How are you doing?",
                "Hope you are doing well?",
                "Hello hope you are doing well?"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Hello, I am great, how are you? Please tell me your GeniSys user",
                "Hello, how are you? I am great thanks! Please tell me your GeniSys user",
                "Hello, I am good thank you, how are you? Please tell me your GeniSys user",
                "Hi, I am great, how are you? Please tell me your GeniSys user",
                "Hi, how are you? I am great thanks! Please tell me your GeniSys user",
                "Hi, I am good thank you, how are you? Please tell me your GeniSys user",
                "Hi, good thank you, how are you? Please tell me your GeniSys user"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "CourtesyGreetingUserRequest",
                "clear": true
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "CourtesyGreetingResponse",
            "text": [
                "Good thanks! My user is Adam",
                "Good thanks! This is Adam",
                "Good thanks! I am Adam",
                "Good thanks! It is Adam",
                "Great thanks! My user is Bella",
                "Great thanks! This is Bella",
                "Great thanks! I am Bella",
                "Great thanks! It is Bella"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Great! Hi <HUMAN>! How can I help?",
                "Good! Hi <HUMAN>, how can I help you?",
                "Cool! Hello <HUMAN>, what can I do for you?",
                "OK! Hola <HUMAN>, how can I help you?",
                "OK! hi <HUMAN>, what can I do for you?"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "extensions.gHumans.updateHuman",
                "entities": true,
                "responses": [
                    "Great %%HUMAN%%! How can I help?",
                    "Good %%HUMAN%%, how can I help you?",
                    "Cool %%HUMAN%%, what can I do for you?",
                    "OK %%HUMAN%%, how can I help you?",
                    "OK hi %%HUMAN%%, what can I do for you?"
                ]
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "GreetingUserRequest",
                "out": "",
                "clear": true
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": [
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 5,
                    "rangeTo": 6
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 4,
                    "rangeTo": 5
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 3,
                    "rangeTo": 4
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 4,
                    "rangeTo": 5
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 5,
                    "rangeTo": 6
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 4,
                    "rangeTo": 5
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 3,
                    "rangeTo": 4
                },
                {
                    "entity": "HUMAN",
                    "rangeFrom": 3,
                    "rangeTo": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "intent": "CurrentHumanQuery",
            "text": [
                "What is my name?",
                "What do you call me?",
                "Who do you think I am?",
                "What do you think I am?",
                "Who are you talking to?",
                "What name do you call me by?",
                "Tell me my name"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "You are <HUMAN>! How can I help?",
                "Your name is  <HUMAN>, how can I help you?",
                "They call you <HUMAN>, what can I do for you?",
                "Your name is <HUMAN>, how can I help you?",
                "<HUMAN>, what can I do for you?"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "extensions.gHumans.getCurrentHuman",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": [
                    "You are %%HUMAN%%! How can I help?",
                    "Your name is  %%HUMAN%%, how can I help you?",
                    "They call you %%HUMAN%%, what can I do for you?",
                    "Your name is %%HUMAN%%, how can I help you?",
                    "%%HUMAN%%, what can I do for you?"
                ]
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "CurrentHumanQuery",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "NameQuery",
            "text": [
                "What is your name?",
                "What could I call you?",
                "What can I call you?",
                "What do your friends call you?",
                "Who are you?",
                "Tell me your name?"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "You can call me Geni",
                "You may call me Geni",
                "Call me Geni"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "RealNameQuery",
            "text": [
                "What is your real name?",
                "What is your real name please?",
                "What's your real name?",
                "Tell me your real name?",
                "Your real name?",
                "Your real name please?",
                "Your real name please?"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "My name is GeniSys",
                "GeniSys",
                "My real name is GeniSys"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "TimeQuery",
            "text": [
                "What is the time?",
                "What's the time?",
                "Do you know what time it is?",
                "Do you know the time?",
                "Can you tell me the time?",
                "Tell me what time it is?",
                "Time"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "One moment",
                "One sec",
                "One second"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "extensions.gTime.getTime",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": [
                    "The time is %%TIME%%",
                    "Right now it is %%TIME%%",
                    "It is around %%TIME%%"
                ]
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "Thanks",
            "text": [
                "OK thank you",
                "OK thanks",
                "OK",
                "Thanks",
                "Thank you",
                "That's helpful"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "No problem!",
                "Happy to help!",
                "Any time!",
                "My pleasure"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "NotTalking2U",
            "text": [
                "I am not talking to you",
                "I was not talking to you",
                "Not talking to you",
                "Wasn't for you",
                "Wasn't meant for you",
                "Wasn't communicating to you",
                "Wasn't speaking to you"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "OK",
                "No problem",
                "Right"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "UnderstandQuery",
            "text": [
                "Do you understand what I am saying",
                "Do you understand me",
                "Do you know what I am saying",
                "Do you get me",
                "Comprendo",
                "Know what I mean"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Well I would not be a very clever AI if I did not would I?",
                "I read you loud and clear!",
                "I do in deed!"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "Shutup",
            "text": [
                "Be quiet",
                "Shut up",
                "Stop talking",
                "Enough talking",
                "Please be quiet",
                "Quiet",
                "Shhh"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "I am sorry to disturb you",
                "Fine, sorry to disturb you",
                "OK, sorry to disturb you"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "Swearing",
            "text": [
                "fuck off",
                "fuck",
                "twat",
                "shit"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Please do not swear",
                "How rude",
                "That is not very nice"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "GoodBye",
            "text": [
                "Bye",
                "Adios",
                "See you later",
                "Goodbye"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "See you later",
                "Have a nice day",
                "Bye! Come back again soon."
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "CourtesyGoodBye",
            "text": [
                "Thanks, bye",
                "Thanks for the help, goodbye",
                "Thank you, bye",
                "Thank you, goodbye",
                "Thanks goodbye",
                "Thanks good bye"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "No problem, goodbye",
                "Not a problem! Have a nice day",
                "Bye! Come back again soon."
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "WhoAmI",
            "text": [
                "Can you see me?",
                "Do you see me?",
                "Can you see anyone in the camera?",
                "Do you see anyone in the camera?",
                "Identify me",
                "Who am I please"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Let me see",
                "Please look at the camera"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "extensions.gHumans.getHumanByFace",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": [
                    "Hi %%HUMAN%%, how are you?",
                    "I believe you are %%HUMAN%%, how are you?",
                    "You are %%HUMAN%%, how are you doing?"
                ]
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        },
        {
            "intent": "Clever",
            "text": [
                "You are very clever",
                "You are a very clever girl",
                "You are very intelligent",
                "You are a very intelligent girl",
                "You are a genious",
                "Clever girl",
                "Genious"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Thank you, I was trained that way",
                "I was trained well",
                "Thanks, I was trained that way"
            ],
            "extension": {
                "function": "",
                "entities": false,
                "responses": []
            },
            "context": {
                "in": "",
                "out": "",
                "clear": false
            },
            "entityType": "NA",
            "entities": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The model is working well on training but when it comes up on responses, it brings up an error when I send it a greeting message.`tag = intent_list[0]['intentd'] IndexError: list index out of range`

I have tried the other NNmodels like tensorflow and pytorch and they are working fine. I expect when I message it 'hi' it responses with a greeting.